# How to bind values for ANY( VALUES (''),('')...) postgres syntax in R2DBC DatabaseClient of spring boot reactive framework

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-webflux, any, r2dbc

I want to bind my list of string values to a specific query I am using. Here is a part of my query

> WHERE (item_id = ANY(VALUES :item_id ))

Now, as per postgres, they follow syntax like this

> WHERE (item_id = ANY(VALUES ('item1'),('item2'),('item3') ))

And what i am doing is

```
databaseClient.sql(myQuery)
                    .bind("item_id", Parameter.fromOrEmpty(itemsIds, String.class))
                    .map(...)
                    ...
```

But this does not bind the values properly as per syntax of postgres because the syntax requires each values enclose within brackets. I even tried mapping all my List itemIds and added '(' &  ')' at start and end respectively, but this also didn't worked. I can achieve what I want by StringBuilder and manually forming the queries, but I don't want to follow that approach, because I have to everytime form the query I require. Also, I dont want to use ANY(ARRAY[...]), my use case will be use only ANY(VALUES (),(),()...).

Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: I do not know your purpose of the complete sql, the where clause can be replaced with `id in :aList`?

Comment: No @Hantsy, I do know it can be replaced with IN clause too, but there is high performance variation while using IN vs ANY clause. Using Any clause gives us quite good performance instead of using IN clause, might be because our list contains 1k + items. And thus, I am looking for ANY clause only.